# Which crystals can a Geologist collect?

Tags: saboteur-2

The rules say  "When the treasure is split, a Geologist gets as many Gold Pieces as there are crystals visible in the maze of tunnels."

I find this ambiguous. How should I interpret this?

Is it that:

1. "visible" means "visible to the people playing the game", that is, any crystal card that was played but not rock slid? OR
2. "visible" means "visible to the miners", that is, if there is no connection between a ladder and a crystal, it is not counted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frederic Moyersoen, the designer of the game, clarified it should be **option 1** on BGG [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/7735083#7735083) (emphasis mine).

> Consider the geologist as someone who picks up the crystals as they are discovered. As the crystals are printed on the cards and cannot be physically be picked up, we just count the points at the end of the round. **We don't care if a path connects to the crystals or gold.**

Comment: I think we can all agree that they're not actually collected as they are discovered, so if you become a geologist mid-game, you still get to count the gems previously discovered, and you don't get to count the gems on tiles removed by rockslides. The important part is that no connection is required. (Visible to the players)